# How to remove all the agents in a flow chart during the simulation in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to remove all the remaining agents in all the blocks in a flowchart when needed, however, I didn't find any funtion or method from Anylogic to do this. Do you have any idea of how to achieve this?

I tried to write a function which iterates all the blocks, gets the agents in them and removes the agents one by one. But this isn't effective and always throws errors, since I have several different types like `Service`, `Queue`, `Convey`, `ConveyorPath`, `Batch`, `Wait` and so on.

Edit: the code I used. The lists in the for each loops are my collection of different blocks. `Kerze` is the agent type in these blocks. The errors were like some agents might be at two blocks simultaneously and then taken by `enter4` twice, the loops for `Wait` and `Batch` also don't work, where I guess `contents()` isn't the correct function to get the agents in the block.

```
for (ConveyorPath conveyor : ersterTeilConveyor) {
    List list = conveyor.getAgents();
    for (Object a : list) {
        Kerze k = (Kerze) a;
        traceln(k.currentBlock().getName() + " " + k.getIndex());
        conveyor.removeAgent(k);
        enter4.take(k);
    }
}
for (Agent block : ersterTeilBlock) {
    if (block instanceof Queue) {
        Queue queue = (Queue) block;
        int size = queue.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            queue.removeFirst();
        }
    } else if (block instanceof Batch) {
        Batch batch = (Batch) block;
        for (Agent k : batch.contents()) {
            traceln(k.currentBlock().getName() + " " + k.getIndex());
            batch.remove(k);
            enter4.take(k);
        }
    } else if (block instanceof Delay) {
        Delay delay = (Delay) block;
        if (delay.size() > 0) {
            Kerze k = (Kerze) delay.get(0);
            traceln(k.currentBlock().getName() + " " + k.getIndex());
            delay.remove(k);
            enter4.take(k);
        }
    }
}   
for (ConveyorPath conveyor : zweiterTeilConveyor) {
    List list = conveyor.getAgents();
    for (Object a : list) {
        Kerze k = (Kerze) a;
        traceln(k.currentBlock().getName() + " " + k.getIndex());
        conveyor.removeAgent(k);
        enter4.take(k);
    }
}
for (Agent block : zweiterTeilBlock) {
    if (block instanceof Queue) {
        Queue queue = (Queue) block;
        for (Agent k : queue.contents()) {
            traceln(k.currentBlock().getName() + " " + k.getIndex());
            queue.remove(k);
            enter4.take(k);
        }
    } else if (block instanceof Batch) {
        Batch batch = (Batch) block;
        for (Agent k : batch.contents()) {
            traceln(k.currentBlock().getName() + " " + k.getIndex());
            batch.remove(k);
            enter4.take(k);
        }
    } else if (block instanceof Service) {
        Service service = (Service) block;
        int size = service.queueSize();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Kerze k = (Kerze) service.queueGet(i);
                traceln(k.currentBlock().getName() + " " + k.getIndex());
                service.queueRemove(k);
                enter4.take(k);
            }
        }
        if (service.delaySize() > 0) {
            Kerze k2 = (Kerze) service.delayGet(0);
            traceln(k2.currentBlock().getName() + " " + k2.getIndex());
            service.delayRemove(k2);
            enter4.take(k2);
        }
    } else if (block instanceof Wait) {
        Wait wait = (Wait) block;
        for (Agent k : wait.contents()) {
            traceln(k.currentBlock().getName() + " " + k.getIndex());
            wait.remove(k);
            enter4.take(k);
        }
    }
}
```

An error was :

```
Exception during discrete event execution:

root.enter4.output.output:

Internal error: agent 34291 is already pending as 'ready' on some other port: root.enter4.output.output.out

java.lang.RuntimeException: root.enter4.output.output:

Internal error: agent 34291 is already pending as 'ready' on some other port: root.enter4.output.output.out

    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ExtEntityImpl.c(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.notifyReady(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer.take(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Enter.take(Unknown Source)

    at prozess.Main.removeKerzen2(Main.java:7449)

    at prozess.Main._sink2_onEnter_xjal(Main.java:6164)

    at prozess.Main$14.onEnter(Main.java:1895)

    at prozess.Main$14.onEnter(Main.java:1)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Sink.b(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Sink$1.onEnter(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.b(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.receiveImmediately(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.PlainTransfer$1.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.action(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal$a.execute(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler$i.execute(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.f(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.fn(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$i.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: show the code you used

Comment: Hi I just added them in the question body, thanks in advance :)

Comment: what error do you get... this is for sure an extremely bad practice for modeling... but it should work in general

Comment: The error was "Internal error: agent 34291 is already pending as 'ready' on some other port: root.enter4.output.output.out" in short. I guess some agents are at two blocks at the same time, so it would be removed in two loops twice, causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to totally answer your question maybe but this is something you can't do:

```
for (Agent k : batch.contents()) {
            batch.remove(k);
            enter4.take(k);
        }
```

Instead you need to create a list of agents in the batch first

```
List <Agent> as=new ArrayList();
for (Agent k : batch.contents()) {
   as.add(k);
}
for (Agent k : as) {
            batch.remove(k);
            enter4.take(k);
        }
```

Comment: Hi I tried your method but it seems not working, either... the batch.contents() is always null.

Comment: Then I tried another inefficient way, which is to create a collection and add every agent to the collection on batch enter and remove them again on batch add. With the help of this collection I can finally remove the agents in the batch block anytime. But it's still not elegant...